# How do I perform a regex test in bash that starts with spaces and includes quotation marks?

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that will change the `fill` color of certain elements within SVG files. I'm inexperienced with shell scripting, but I'm good with regexes (...in JS).

Here's the SVG tag I want to modify:

```xml
<!-- is the target because its ID is exactly "the.target" -->
<path id="the.target" d="..." style="fill:#000000" />
```

Here's the bash code I've got so far:

```sh
local newSvg="" # will hold newly-written SVG file content
while IFS="<$IFS" read tag
do
    if [[ "${tag}" =~ +id *= *"the\.target" ]]; then
        tag=$(echo "${tag}" | sed 's/fill:[^;];/fill:${color};/')
    fi
    newSvg="${newSvg}${tag}"
done < ${iconSvgPath} # is an argument to the script
```

Explained: I'm using `read` (splitting the file on `<` via custom `IFS`) to read the SVG content tag by tag. For each tag, I test to see if it includes an `id` property with the exact value I want. If it doesn't, I add this tag as-is to a `newSvg` string that I will later write to a file. If the tag *does* have the desired ID, I'll used `sed` to replace `fill:STUFF;` with `fill:${myColor};`. (Note that my `sed` is also failing, but that's not what I'm asking about here.)

It fails to find the right line with the test `[[ "${tag}" =~ +id *= *"the\.target" ]]`.

It succeeds if I change the test to `[[ "${tag}" =~ \"the\.target\" ]]`.

I'm not happy with the working version because it's too brittle. While I don't intend to support *all* the flexibility of XML, I would like to be tolerant of semantically irrelevant whitespace, as well as the id property being anywhere within the tag. Ideally, the regex I'd like to write would express:

- `id` (preceded by at least one whitespace)
- followed by zero or more whitespaces
- followed by `=`
- followed by zero or more whitespaces
- followed by `"the.target"`

I think I'm not delimiting the regex properly inside the `[[ ... =~ REGEX ]]` construction, but none of the answers I've seen online use *any* delimiters whatsoever. In javascript, regex literals are bounded (e.g. `/ +id *= *"the\.target"/`), so it's straightforward beginning a regex with a whitespace character that you care about. Also, JS doesn't have any magic re: `*`, whereas bash is 50% magic-handling-of-asterisks.

Any help is appreciated. My backup plan is maybe to try to use `awk` instead (which I'm no better at).

---

EDIT: My sed was really close. I forgot to add `+` after the `[^;]` set. Oof.

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: That is an incredible answer. Yeah, regexes have limits. I believe this is the same reason why it's practically impossible to write a regex that tests for all syntactically valid email addresses. That said, this is such a simple use-case that I don't want to add a dependency.

Comment: @Tom : You don't _delimit_ the regexp. You can represent a literal space always as `\ ` (i.e. backslash, followed by space).

Comment: So... Would `[[ "${tag}" =~ id\ *=\ *"the\.target" ]]` be closer to what you're looking for? Options to the `test` command are separated by spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much easier if you define regular expression pattern in a variable :

```
tag='      id  =   "the.target"'
pattern=' +id *= *"the\.target"'

if  [[ $tag =~ $pattern ]]; then
    echo matched.
fi
```

Comment: This isn't the exact solution I used, and there's wisdom in steering me towards a proper XML parser for my larger goal, but this is probably the best response that engages directly with the question as written: "regex test in bash that starts with spaces". I also like how it encourages extraction of magic values. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for giving us such a clear example that *regex* is *not* the way to solve this problem.

A SVG file is an XML file, and a possible tool to modify these is **xmlstarlet**.

Try this script I called **modifycolor**:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# invoke as: modifycolor <svg.file> <target_id> <new_color>

xmlstarlet edit \
  --update "//path[@id = '$2']/@style" --value "fill:#$3" \
  "$1"
```

Assuming the svg file is **test.svg**, invoke it as:

```sh
./modifycolor test.svg the.target ff0000
```

You will be astonished by the result.

If you want to paste a piece of code inside your bash script, try this:

```sh
target="the.target"
newSvg=$(xmlstarlet edit \
  --update "//path[@id = '${target}']/@style" --value "fill:#${myColor}" \
  "${iconSvgPath}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to folks for pointing out the mistakes in my bash-fu, I came up with this code which does what I said I wanted. I will not be marking this as the accepted answer because, as folks have observed, regex is a bad way to operate on XML. Sharing this for posterity.

```sh
local newSvg="" # will hold newly-written SVG code
while IFS="<$IFS" read tag
do
  if [[ "${tag}" =~ \ +id\ *=\ *\"the\.target\" ]]; then
    tag=$(echo "${tag}" | sed -E 's/fill:[^;]+;/fill:'"${color}"';/')
  fi
  newSvg="${newSvg}${tag}"
done < ${iconSvgPath}
```

Fixes:

1. escape the whitespace in the regex: `=~ \ +id\ *=\ *`
2. for `sed`, switch to double-quotes for the variable in the pattern
3. also for `sed`, I added the `-E` extended regex flag in order to support the negated set `[^;]`

Re: XML, I'll be comparing the list of available CLI-friendly XML parsers to the set of tools commonly available on my users' machines.